# Uncommon tensor notation $\partial_{(\mu}\xi_{\nu)}$

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus, notation

I came across this expression for the change in a metric under an infinitesimal gauge transformation $\epsilon\xi^\mu$.

$$h_{\mu\nu}' = h_{\mu\nu}+2\epsilon\partial_{(\mu}\xi_{\nu)}$$

What does the $\partial_{(\mu}\xi_{\nu)}$ in the last term mean?

Comment: PS - That notation is in fact very very common.

Comment: I don't doubt it, but it was introduced out of nowhere in the text I was reading (actually the notation with $()$ and $[]$ for permutations and antipermutations was discussed but I didn't realize it applied here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it should be:

$$h^\prime_{\mu\nu} = h_{\mu\nu} + 2\epsilon\,\partial_{(\mu}\xi_{\nu)}$$

where the parentheses denote the symmetric part of the tensor in the $\mu$ and $\nu$ indices:

$$h^\prime_{\mu\nu} = h_{\mu\nu} + \epsilon\,\left(\partial_{\mu}\xi_{\nu} + \partial_{\nu}\xi_{\mu} \right)$$

It is a generalization of the usual definition:

$$ A_{(\mu\nu)} = \frac{1}{2}\left( A_{\mu\nu} + A_{\nu\mu} \right)$$

The objects $\partial_\nu \xi_\mu$ are really the components of a second rank tensor $\tilde{\partial}\otimes \tilde{\xi}$ (or 2-form if you prefer).  You need to symmetrize that tensor to ensure the metric is still symmetric after the gauge transformation.

Comment: Why can I call it a 2-form? Forms are antisymmetrized object.

Comment: @Minkyu -- The outer product is an anti-symmetric product, but that doesn't mean that all 2nd rank tensors are anti-symmetric tensors.  The outer product of a 1st rank tensor with itself is a 2nd rank tensor that is clearly symmetric.  2nd rank tensors are functions that take two arguments and output a scalar.  The symmetry is in the exchange of the two arguments.